# Avoid resetting ViewStates with Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application I have two, a ViewState and a Session which hold values, the problem is that I need to reset one and leave the other as it is through a click of a button. If I use `Response.Redirect` in my button, both the ViewState and the Session are resetted. I tried using if(!IsPostBack) but I don't think this would work in a button event. I would really appreciate your suggestions and help.

CODE:

// There is a ViewState above this code which I have to reset

```
   protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["Counter"] = (int)Session["Counter"] + 1; // I do not want to reset this Session.
       Label1.Text = Session["Counter"].ToString();
       Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx"); // If this button is pressed then Session["counter"] is resetted which I don't want to happen


}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: I think you have a different problem here if your `Response.Redirect` resets the value you have in session, as that implies your Page1.aspx overwrites your session value.

Comment: Is your intent simply to have the text in the label increment with every button click?

Comment: @Tejs yes, and using Response.Redirect resets the counter which I don't want it to happen.

Comment: Look for somewhere elses which is accessing Session["Counter"] in your app. You're probably resetting it in another place. Is it in Page1 Page_Load? Look for Session["Counter"] in all the files in the solution (Ctrl+Shift+F, choose "all files in solution") and lokk for it.

Comment: @Tejs Yes it is defined there `Session["Counter"]` = 1 within an `if(!IsPostBack)` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to incremement the counter, all you need to do is this:

```
 public override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        if (Session["PersistedCounter"] == null)
            Session["PersistedCounter"] = "0";

        Label1.Text = Session["PersistedCounter"];
     }
 }

 protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int oldValue = int.Parse(Label1.Text);
     Label1.Text = (oldValue + 1).ToString();
     Session["PersistedCounter"] = Label1.Text;
 }
```

Since the page already saves state, the label will post back to the server with it's current value restored from view state. You simply pull the value, and then set the value with your modifications. Try that, and it should work.

Your solution is actually overcomplicating things.

Comment: However, if I want to reset the ViewState above in the code using `Reponse.Redirect` its working fine but even with the `label1.Text` is in the `(!IsPostBack)`, the label is still being reset to 0.

Comment: Do you want the label to retain it's counter regardless of initial visit or subsequent visits? The above code will only work if you want to remain on the same page and increment the counter.

Comment: I am using `Response.Redirect` to the same page itself. Which means that everything is resetted. What I want is that I want to make the label (counter) retain its value without resetting it regardless of firing `Respone.Redirect`.

Comment: Updated with the persistence.

Comment: could you just explain me what difference it made with `if(Session["PersistedCounter"] == null)` ??

Comment: Initially, that session key will have no value, meaning it is null. If you tried to set the text without initially setting the session variable, you would simply get an empty string (or, more accurately, a null string). That's simply testing for the existence of the set key.